# Что значит режим MySQL "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"?

Tags: mysql

Что значит режим MySQL `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`?

```
SET SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

Какие настройки изменятся в базе данных после установки этого режима?

P.S. документацию читала, но на английском, и поняла очень смутно. Будет здорово, если будут ссылки на русскую документацию...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table test_ai(id int auto_increment primary key, val int) engine=innodb;
insert into test_ai (id, val) values (0, 1);
```

Вот какой результат будет в поле id и зависит от этого `sql_mode`:

Без `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` будет сгенерировано следующее значение auto_increment. С установленным флагом `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` будет записан именно 0.

> mysql> SET SQL_MODE='';
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
>
> mysql> insert into test_ai (id, val) values (0, 1);
>   Query OK, 1 row affected (0,01 sec)
>
> mysql> SET SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
>
> mysql> insert into test_ai (id, val) values (0, 2);
>   Query OK, 1 row affected (0,01 sec)
>
> mysql> select * from test_ai;
>   +----+------+
>   | id | val  |
>   +----+------+
>   |  0 |    2 |
>   |  1 |    1 |
>   +----+------+
>   2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
>
> mysql> insert into test_ai (id, val) values (0, 3);
>   ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

На запросы такого вида настройка не влияет:

```
insert into test_ai (id, val) values (NULL, 1);
insert into test_ai (val) values (1);
```

Общий смысл: не надо полю auto_increment вообще пытаться присваивать явные значения.